# determine string index vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

I have this string:

```
TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2
```

and I have this array:

```
Private _Joins() As String = {"JOIN", "INNER JOIN", "LEFT JOIN", "RIGHT JOIN"}
```

Now, I would like to determine the index of JOIN. With IndexOf I can simply get the index, but if I have this string:

```
TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2
```

then I get the wrong index. Of course, I could put JOIN in the array at the end, but this isn't a solution.

What I need is an exact match. I mean I iterate through the array and if there is a match, I get the index in the string. But in this case, JOIN would be a match and not LEFT JOIN. Which results in incorrect index.

How could I get it to work?

Comment: In your second case, JOIN and LEFT JOIN are both exact match. You'll have to give LEFT JOIN a priority somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN and INNER JOIN are redundant. You really just need an array like this:

> {"INNER JOIN", "LEFT JOIN", "RIGHT JOIN"}

And once you have that, you'll notice that you always use the word join, and so you can change your code to always supply that part and only look for the first part in an array like this:

> {"INNER", "LEFT", "RIGHT"}

At this point, your index lookup becomes much simpler. While we're here, we should add the final join types, for completeness:

> {"INNER", "LEFT", "RIGHT", "FULL", "CROSS"}

Of course, this assumes you have some measure of control over the SQL code you're looking at. If you don't, there are many different combinations of ways to write a join, that may also involve the use of the "OUTER" keyword, or may not even use the "JOIN" keyword at all (that A,B join syntax needs to just die already).

For what it's worth, I almost never use RIGHT or CROSS joins. Every right join can be re-written as a left  join instead, and cross joins only have a few very specialized uses. But I do find FULL JOIN to be quite handy at times.

I'm also concerned about this for security reasons. The kind of sql string manipulation you're looking at tends to lend itself to code that will result in awful, wide open sql injection vulnerabilities. You may have accounted for this, and if so, good for you, but I've seen this *way* too often not to at least mention it. If you know don't know about sql injection, you need to stop building sql code with .Net strings until you understand it.

Comment: @Luminous OUTER is not necessary. LEFT, RIGHT, FULL, and CROSS are just special types of outer joins. If you say "OUTER JOIN" with no other qualifier, you're really doing a "LEFT OUTER JOIN", or just "LEFT JOIN". Since you can always use one of those special types along with the join keyword, including OUTER becomes redundant and needlessly verbose.

Comment: my purpose isn't manipulate sql query, my purpose is analyse sql query
I don't deal with sql injection

Comment: If that's true, you should look at tools like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to do the parsing.